# Delete value by key in user meta array in WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I've this array set to a WordPress user on my WordPress page:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1509
            [1] => 1597
        )

)
```

To receive this array I'm doing this:

```
$get_ids = get_user_meta( 3, 'additional_ids', false );
```

---

So good, so far! Now I've a little problem because for example I need to remove the value **1509** from the `user_meta`. So I thirst tried to find out the key by the value which works good for the moment:

```
$key = array_search( (int) $value, $get_ids[0], true );
```

So I've found out now that the key is `[0]`. But how can I delete this now a smart way from the user meta and save it that my meta data array looks like this after saving it:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1597
        )

)
```

**This is what I've tried:**

```
//Unset element to delete from the array
unset( $get_ids[0][ $key ] );


//Save it again in the database
update_user_meta( 3, 'additional_ids', $get_ids, false );
```

But when I do this the array is totally messed up and not longer readable.

Comment: Means, there are chances of multiple arrays and you dont want to specify ```$get_ids[0]``` right?

Comment: There is just one first array [0] thats because I'm working with 0 here. And I want to remove a child from this parent array in my meta_data field I named in the question. And I don't care the way it should just work. If it's possible to do it without a bug function it would be better but I needs to work for the moment.

Comment: Use ```array_pop($get_ids[0]);```. Note: it always removes first element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing we need to address is **how** you added the meta to your user. If you use [`add_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta), you can add *multiple* meta values under the same meta key. Like this:

```
//add_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );
add_user_meta(3, 'additional_ids', 1597, false);
add_user_meta(3, 'additional_ids', 1509, false);
```

Doing this will add **both** 1509 and 1597 to the user meta `additional_ids`.

If you've added the meta fields this way, it will allow you to get all values by using [`get_user_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) like this:

```
$additional_ids = get_user_meta(3, 'additional_ids', false);
```

Which will return an array like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1597
    [1] => 1509
)
```

You can however delete any value from the array *without* grabbing the array first by using [`delete_user_meta();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_user_meta/) to remove that specific value.

Like this:

```
delete_user_meta( 3, 'additional_ids', 1509 );
```

Which would mean that if you get the additional ids again, it would look like this:

```
$additional_ids = get_user_meta(3, 'additional_ids', false);
print_r($additional_ids);
//prints out:
Array (
    [0] => 1597
)
```

The third argument inside that function will ensure that only metadata with that specific value will be removed.

Doing it this way removes the need to try and find the key associated to the value you want to delete, and will also ensure that you don't accidentally mess with any of the other values that may or may not be in that array.

Comment: Tried exact the same thing but the array is still the same after doing the delete function.

Comment: Oh I see, the problem is that you have saved all your ids into an array, and added it to a single instance of user meta, instead of saving to multiple instances. Not sure if you are aware of this, but you can keep adding meta with the same meta_key, and when you `get_user_meta` you receive back an array of all of those saved values. Once it runs that way, you will be able to make use of the `delete_user_meta` appropriately. - hope it helps :) @Mr.Jo

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you meant with adding meta :D

Comment: Can you update your answer? This would be very helpful! Thank you sir!

Comment: @Mr.Jo - sure thing, I've updated it to show the full process of adding and removing meta using the native meta array capabilities.

Comment: I've tried to add 2 values into one key but thats not working. I just can set one value. The second one isn't visible. Is it even possible two add 2 values in one key?

Comment: @Mr.Jo - ah, that's because I made a mistake with the `add_user_meta()` third argument, it should be false, not true. I've edited my answer to show the correct statement :)

Comment: I'm currently implementing these changes you've made. I'll let you know if it works today and tick your answer! Thank you so much for your time you spent on this.

Comment: You know whats funny? I've also thought about this in the past but I don't got it with a normal array. I thought I need to pass an array but this ended in a multidimensional one - funny. So now it's working and you deserve a big thank you :)

Comment: @Mr.Jo I’m super happy to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

after you do the unset() you will just need to update $get_ids[0] with array_values() to rebase the array again

```
//Unset element to delete from the array
unset( $get_ids[0][ $key ] );

// rebase the array
$get_ids[0] = array_values( $get_ids[0] );

//Save it again in the database
update_user_meta( 3, 'additional_ids', $get_ids, false );
```